# Graphviz Array LR but stacked TB

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph G
{
    rankdir=LR;

    Array1 [ shape = record, label = "{ <a1>A(1) | <a2>A(2) | <a3>A(...) | <an>A(n)}"] ; 
    Array2 [ shape = record, label = "{ <b1>B(1) | <b2>B(2) | <b3>B(...) | <bn1>B(n+1)}"] ;  
    Array1:a1 -> Array2:b1 [style=solid];
    Array1:an -> Array2:bn1 [style=solid];
    {rank=same; Array1; Array2;}
}
```

I'm trying to get graphviz plot two array from left to right but Array1 on the top and Array2 at the bottom.

[Output with rank=same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A9bv.png)

As you can see in the picture there are no arrows drawn but the layout is like it should be. I'm also getting some errors from dot, but I can't find anything useful with that information:

```
dot -Tpng algoA.dot -o algoA.png                                         :(
Warning: flat edge between adjacent nodes one of which has a record shape - replace records with HTML-like labels
  Edge Array2 -> Array1
Error: lost Array1 Array2 edge
Error: lost Array1 Array2 edge
```

---

```
digraph G
{
    rankdir=LR;

    Array1 [ shape = record, label = "{ <a1>A(1) | <a2>A(2) | <a3>A(...) | <an>A(n)}"] ; 
    Array2 [ shape = record, label = "{ <b1>B(1) | <b2>B(2) | <b3>B(...) | <bn1>B(n+1)}"] ;  
    Array1:a1 -> Array2:b1 [style=solid];
    Array1:an -> Array2:bn1 [style=solid];
    //{rank=same; Array1; Array2;}
}
```

[Output with rank=same removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttN7Q.png)

Without rank=same in the code I get the arrows like I wanted, but not like I wanted it with Array1 on top and Array2 on the bottom. The error messages are gone. What am I doing wrong? I tried several ways and all of them didn't work for me, I'm always getting a wrong layout or I have to add several other nodes to get it drawn, with those invisible the arrows for my arrays also don't get drawn.

Answer (score 2):

The key is in the error message: `replace records with HTML-like labels`. Details can be found [here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).

Taking your code and what I understand you want to achieve, this can be done with creating your arrays as two HTML-like labels. Comments in the code.

```
digraph so 
{
    # plaintext is being used to create HTML-like labels
    node [shape=plaintext]

    # no border for the table, a single border for each cell and
    # no distance between individual cells looks like record shape

    # PORTs being defined as addresses of individual cells
    # that edges can be directed to

    array1 [label=< 
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0"> <TR>
            <TD PORT="a1">A(1)</TD>
            <TD PORT="a2">A(2)</TD>
            <TD PORT="ax">A(...)</TD>
            <TD PORT="an">A(n)</TD>
        </TR> </TABLE>>];

    array2 [label=< 
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0"> <TR>
            <TD PORT="b1">B(1)</TD>
            <TD PORT="b2">B(2)</TD>
            <TD PORT="bx">B(...)</TD>
            <TD PORT="bn">B(n+1)</TD>
    </TR> </TABLE>>]; 

    array1:a1 -> array2:b1;
    array1:an -> array2:bn;
}
```

This produces what (I think) you want:

[image]